# How can I transform canvas path automatically?

Tags: android, opencv, android-canvas

[image: Canvas with 2 path]

How can I transform `left path` into `right path` automatically? Do I need AI? or do I have to code manually?
I need anything that can be helpful for me.
**I have tried to achieve this(for circle only) using manually coding and it works. But I get unexpected result in few cases(like when `path` is small or for small rectangle).**

Comment: I don't know why image is not loading. Tell me if you face the same problem

Comment: train a ml model to find the shape and use it. you might find tenserflow model online

Comment: Can you give me link? I don't know AI

Comment: try this https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/